# Jquery Radio button not showing selected div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using jquery to display div upon selection which is store to database

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery("input[name$='advert_specifications[link_type]']").click(function(){

            var radio_value = jQuery(this).val();

            if(radio_value=='advert_page') {
                jQuery("#urlbox").hide('fast');
            }
            else if(radio_value=='external_link') {
                jQuery("#urlbox").show('fast');
            }
        });

        jQuery("#urlbox").hide();

    }); 
</script>



<div class="my_meta_control">

    <!--[advert link type group]-->
    <div class="left side clearfix">
        <label class="left sub_label"><input type="radio" value="advert_page" name="advert_specifications[link_type]"> Page Link</label>        
        <label class="left sub_label"><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="external_link" name="advert_specifications[link_type]"> External Link</label>
    </div>
    <!--[end of advert link type group]-->

    <div id="urlbox" style="display: none;">            
        <p class="sidebox clearform">
            <label>Advert External Link</label>     
            <input type="text" class="mydatepicker" value="" name="advert_specifications[advert_url]" id="advertdate">
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

It is working fine on click function but once I select external link radio and save to db than re open the post than #urlbox is always hide where it should be visible if external link radio button selected.

EDIT:

I tried this code and it does the same thing hiding `# + test` div on load

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("div.links").hide();
    jQuery("input[name$='advert_specifications[link_type]']").click(function() {
        var test = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery("div.links").hide();
        jQuery("#" + test).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, This is wordpress post metabox. So once I selected External link and if I open the post again to edit than alsways #urlbox div I found hidden and so need to click again on External Link radio button to show it....I am using WPAlchemy metabox http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my understing in you main script you are hiding the main block. Although its not needed because you are alreadying saying display none in your markup.

Please check the jsfiddle link

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/DFPAX/

Answer (score -1):

it will be always hide because you have written the code to hide the box (#urlbox) in second last line in script tag. Which will always execute when page loads.

Comment: I know that there is something wrong with my code and that is why I posted here.

Comment: one thing can be done that you maintain that you are coming on page after clicking on external link radio, so when you come this way you add this condition in your script code and then show according to that.